# Automated farms in MCPE?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

How can I make automated Farms in MCPE now that Pistons, Droppers.etc have been added?

Comment: What kind of farm? It will vary drastically based on what your goal is

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend looking at videos on YouTube. This is how I do any complicated redstone builds because frankly, I'm not good with redstone :p. Once you get some experience though you will see patterns with certain redstone clocks and contraptions and will be able to build your own designs!

See here to build an [automatic wheat farm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kRAIITO67qY), or here to build [12 useful farms for pocket edition](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TdaSAH910EE)

Answer (score 0):

Make a contraption using red stone and dispensers. On the dispensers add water,

Comment: Thanks for this answer Jacob, but do you think you could add some more detail for people who aren't as familiar with this? An annotated picture or two would be a great addition.